# BulkCopy Vs BCP Insert

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, silverlight, sql-server-2008

I need to insert a huge amount of data into different tables within my database. 
Which options can I choose so that performance will never be an issue? (It is a silverlight application and I will run this on the server from the client side.) I found some options like BulkCopy in SMO and BCP Insert. Which would be the best for my scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SqlBulkCopy class instead.
I've been using it many times, it's very efficient and easy to use.

Take a look at this post:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/dcc7a701-9acf-4c2f-a5d7-1fcb4dbb05f2

Example for using it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Comment: yes friend. I found BulkCopy Class very easy to understand and work with. But I was looking for something faster. Any idea which one would be?

Comment: In one of the links I sent you, the guy says that both BCP and bulk insert work the same.

Comment: Do you  have any indexes on the tables?
If you do, you might be thinking of dropping them and rebuild after the transfer is finished.

Comment: hi, I went on searching for new **Bulk Insert Operation** on SQL and found a link. Please have a look at it before you really suit one.

link :[Bulk Inserts via TSQL in SQL Server](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/bulk-inserts-via-tsql-in-sql-server/)